# Overlaying a image in a div?

Tags: html, css

This is hard to explain so I've put together this JSFiddle. I want the black div to cut through the blue box so that the black div is underneath the horizontal blue lines. So I'd like the `<div class="title">Testing</div>` to overlay the `<div class="middleFifth">`

http://jsfiddle.net/Zhxt9/

TIA in advance and sorry for the bad explanation!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zhxt9/4/ you mean something like this?

Comment: Yes but the only problem is that when resizing the position of the black bar moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relatively position the black div and set the z-index so that it is behind the blue div (also must specify z-index on blue div).

```
.title{
    width:100%; float:left; 
    background-color:black;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zhxt9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.title{
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zhxt9/1/

Or other options would be:

```
.title {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```

or:

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Depending on the rest of your page

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're aiming for, but you could try something like:

```
.title{
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    background-color:black;

    /* Below properties are what I added */
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: -10; 
}
```

Obviously you should change the z-index to a more sensible value by setting it on your other elements, but I included it here for simplicity's sake.